# EXCEL Formulas Sum Everything above specific row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to SUM everything above a cell that contains the word "SUMTOTAL". So if I have 50 columns I want it to go to first row that has the text "SUMTOTAL" in it and then Sum everything aboce that word. Is it possible?

Comment: Is the next row after SUMTOTAL blank?

Comment: Do you want to sum all 50 columns from row 1 to the row above the row that contains *SUMTOTAL* or just the column that contains it? Is the use of *SUMTOTAL* restricted to a single column or could it be anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use a MATCH formula to find the row and minus one from it then use an INDIRECT formula to put together a string of the address then plop it into a sum formula like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A" & MATCH("SUMTOTAL",B:B,0)-1))
```

Assumption:

SUMTOTAL is in column B somewhere

The numbers you want to sum are in column A

Your data starts at row 1.

You are summing ONE column. To expand simply change "A1:A" to "A1:X" if you wanted to sum columns A to X

Comment: You can remove the *volatile* `INDIRECT` with something like `=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("SUMTOTAL",B:B,0)-1))`.

Comment: Thank you. But If I have 5 sumTotals in one column the formula will only sum all columns before the first SUMTOTAL: If I want it to go to the next one and do the same is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all your data is located in A1:N20, and SUMTOTAL appears somewhere inside this area (you can easily change the desired data location). The following formula does the summation of all numbers directly above SUMTOTAL, i.e., in the same column.

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,0,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($A$1:$N$20)*($A$1:$N$20="SUMTOTAL"))-1,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$1:$N$20)*($A$1:$N$20="SUMTOTAL"))-1))
```

If you want to sum all numbers above SUMTOTAL, no matter if in the same column or not, use

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$1:$N$20)*($A$1:$N$20="SUMTOTAL"))-1,COLUMNS($A$1:$N$20)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))
```